# AAC submits report to VC

Tags: grammar

"Academic Audit Committee submits report to the Vice Chancellor" - What does it convey? Does it mean the committee has submitted its report or will submit its report?

Comment: To those who closed this question as "general reference": which reference is it, exactly, that will clarify this subtle point of whether the simple present in this case has past or future meaning?

Answer (score 2):

Without context we can't tell for sure.

This is most likely to occur in a news summary, or headline, in which case it is the [historic present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present) and refers to things that have already happened.

But if it occurred in a schedule of "what's on in the coming week", for example, it would refer to future time.

Comment: In an University, the Registrar has issued a schedule of Academic Audit Committee meetings to assess the performance of the faculty members.  The University runs a daily paper wherein the heading was put like that.  Actually the AAC has to meet several times and release its final report.  when enquired, it was told that it means that AAC will submit its report. This is the context.

Comment: Ah. I see why you were unsure. But the context then is a schedule rather than a news report, so the future meaning is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Academic Audit Committee submits report to the Vice Chancellor" could mean it is the protocol or norm.